# jQuery Modal window only working on Chrome but not FF & IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-window

Login popup style=display:none only popup in Chrome but not Firefox16.0.1 and IE9.

Any advise or fix are welcome. I follow tutorial at:[tutorial](http://freetexthost.com/ydjkbmwixb)

http://jsfiddle.net/6TaQt/8/

Comment: You have error in your fiddle. Its not working in FF. I got this TypeError: $("label.overlabel").overlabel is not a function when running the fiddle in FF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the markup issue also. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6TaQt/7/)
This works in FF also and in chrome.

You have to enclose button inside a tag. not a tag inside button tag.

All other are right you have error of overlabel function

Comment: TQ! Sorry all. The label function wasn't used on this login popup. Thanks Zahid. it works on Chrome, IE and FF now.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug this error message first "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'overlabel' ", actually what I don't get is how this possibly works in Chrome :)

Comment: The error happens in both. Difference probably is that Chrome continues to run after the error happens, but Firefox stops execution of the rest of the JS.